# Why cookies from dev tools are not presented in document.cookie?

Tags: dom, cookies

Chrome Dev Tools shows me a lot more cookies than `document.cookie`.

For example, `LOGIN_INFO`:

[image: screenshot of dev tools, tab 'application']

Checking this in `document.cookie`:

```js
document.cookie.indexOf('LOGIN_INFO'); // -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some cookies are HTTP-only.
This means that the cookie won't be accessible by scripting languages, such as JavaScript. This setting can effectively help to reduce identity theft through XSS attacks (although it is not supported by all browsers).